# Brush tool soft light now showing up on white background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I'm making a youtube banner and I used the brush tool as I usually do to create a shadow behind an image. I set the colour to black and then I set the layer's effect to soft light. When I added a white background it did not show up. However when I remove it I can see it on the transparent background. The white layer is below the brush layer.

[image: White Background]

[image: No background]

Comment: Your problem is the layer blending mode "soft light". Choose another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Soft light` blend mode actually calculates a **lighter** variance based upon the pixels data of the layer and what is below it. If white is below a layer set to `Soft Light`, there's nothing *lighter* than white. Therefore using the `soft light` blend mode won't show any change.

Use a different blend mode or use `Normal` and lower the opacity of your black brush stroke layer.

Answer (score 0):

All the layer with only shadows must have its blend mode to *Multiply*. 
So you can play with its *opacity* to make it darker or not.
When you put a layer filled with white with soft light it will lighten the layer below. It is not a good thing to do.